# How do I override my SOAP requests when __call() is deprecated?

Tags: php, xml, soap, webservice-client

I have extended the SoapClient for authentication and would like to manipulate the request parameters **before they are encoded into xml**.

I am informed __call() is deprecated and thought __soapCall() was the successor of it. But calling $soapclient->anymethod() does not trigger __soapCall(). Is it not a magic method as __get() is deprecated? How else would I override the requests for adding my Authentication node?

https://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.call